# ReferenceError: Error #1069 Actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, reference

So i have been stuck on this for about 2 weeks and i have no idea how to progress.

I have an array of movie clips called    "_main.speederArray"    and i'm trying to make it so that if they collide with each other then they are both destroyed. Here is my code in the "Speeder class" to detect collision.

```
private function detectionHandler():void{
        //trace("array length", _main.speederArray.length);
        detectionID = _main.gameCounter;
        for ( var i:int = _main.speederArray.length -1; i >= 0; i--){

            var speeder:Speeder = _main.speederArray[i];

            if(speeder.destroyMe) continue;
            if(speeder.detectionID == this.detectionID) continue;

            if (boxIntersect(this, speeder)){

                    trace("collision");

                    destroyMe = true;
                    speeder.destroyMe = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the boxIntersect function this code refers to. It's in the same class

```
private function boxIntersect ( speeder1:Speeder, speeder2:Speeder):Boolean{

        if(speeder1.x + speeder1.distRight < speeder2.x + speeder2.distLeft) return false; //checking for overlap on X axis
        if(speeder1.x + speeder1.distLeft > speeder2.x + speeder2.distRight) return false;
        if(speeder1.y + speeder1.distBot < speeder2.y + speeder2.distTop) return false; // checking for overlap on Y axis
        if(speeder1.y + speeder1.distTop > speeder2.y + speeder2.distBot) return false;



        return true;

    }
```

And then here is where i think the problem is. I have a class called "spawner" and this is where i was going to handle the objects being created and destroyed. Here is the code where i am trying to splice objects from the array depending on whether the destroyMe bool is set to true. At this stage i have confused the shit out of myself so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    private function updateArray(e:Event):void{

        for(var i:int = _main.speederArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--){


            var speeder:Speeder = _main.speederArray[i];


            if(speeder.destroyMe){
                //trace("hello");
                removeChild(speeder[i]); // take it off the stage
                _main.speederArray[i] = null;
                _main.speederArray.splice(i, 1); //remove it from the array
            }

        }


    }
```

Now, the game runs however as soon as the 2 objects within the same array collide, i get the collision trace in the output window but straight after i get this :

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 1 not found on com.game.Speeder and there is no default value.
    at com.game::Spawner/updateArray()

No idea what it means :(

Any help appreciated thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the line
`removeChild(speeder[i]);` inside your update function.
Speeder has no properties that are called `1` and the 1 comes obviously from your for loop.

So, to solve this problem, you should simply call

`removeChild(speeder);`

`speeder` already is the object at the position `i` of your array. Putting [] behind an object is the same like accessing a property from it. essentially you were doing this:

`removeChild(speeder.1);`

Comment: Thank you so much i love you <3